# Terraform Kubernetes service definitions in individual git repositories?

Tags: git, kubernetes, terraform

Is there a recommended pattern or solution for keeping the definitions of individual Terraform services in their respective code repositories while still being able to update the entire project's infrastructure at once?

We're migrating to GCP from a managed service and already use Github+Actions.

I was thinking of doing this a couple different ways, either through private Terraform Modules on GCS or using git submodules.

While we could use a single central repository for all Terraform files, I would prefer that service definitions live in their respective repositories so as to avoid mistakes and not have future contributors overlook modifying service definitions where appropriate.

Comment: Yes you would use modules and declare them in a root config. Do not use git submodules for anything like this since those are used when no native solution exists in the software/tool.

Comment: On GCP I would also consider Config Connector as an alternative: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/containers-kubernetes/config-connector-bridges-kubernetes-gcp-resources

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at **Terragrunt**: https://terragrunt.gruntwork.io/

When declaring a `terraform` block, a `source` arg can be a link to a different git repo https://terragrunt.gruntwork.io/docs/features/keep-your-terraform-code-dry/#remote-terraform-configurations

To update the entire project at once, there's `terragrunt plan-all`, `terragrunt apply-all`, and very handy `terragrunt graph-dependencies`.

Gruntwork (the org that built this) has a set of free modules https://github.com/gruntwork-io/, a set of paid modules (monthly subscription), and of course, you can use your own modules.

Comment: Had a read through the docs, so it also looks like in order to access those remote configs I would enable SSH auth, sound correct? https://terragrunt.gruntwork.io/docs/features/keep-your-terraform-code-dry/#using-terragrunt-with-private-git-repos

Comment: Yes, for the private repos, the machine where you're running terragrunt should have ssh access to the repos to pull. It basically pulls all the dependencies into `.terragrunt-cache` and then runs terraform.